# Java - Modifying a class to compute total number of objects created

Tags: java, arrays

Currently, I'm working on a small practice beginner program with 3 classes, that I'm trying to modify.  I want to modify class Student so that it computes the total number of objects created, and I want to modify class Course so that it includes an array of the Student class.  Here is what I have so far; any assistance would be appreciated.  I'm sure its obvious, and I'm just being dense:

Class Course:

```
public class Course {
  private String courseName;
  private Student[]
  students = new Student[100];
  private int numberOfStudents;

  public Course(String courseName) {
    this.courseName = courseName;
  }

  public void addStudent(String[] Student) {
    Student[numberOfStudents] = students[];
    numberOfStudents++;
  }

  public Student[] getStudents() {
    return students;
  }

  public int getNumberOfStudents() {
    return numberOfStudents;
  }  

  public String getCourseName() {
    return courseName;
  }  

  public void dropStudent(String student) {

  }
}
```

Class Student:

```
public class Student {
private int id;
private String name;
private java.util.Date dateCreated;

public Student(int ssn, String newName) {
    id = ssn;
    name = newName;
    dateCreated = new java.util.Date();
}

public int getID() {
    return id; 
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public java.util.Date getDateCreated() {
    return dateCreated;
}
}
```

And the driver class, class TestCourse:

```
public class TestCourse {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
     Course course1 = new Course("Data Structures");
     Course course2 = new Course("Database Systems");

course1.addStudent("Peter Jones",);
course1.addStudent("Brian Smith");
course1.addStudent("Anne Kennedy");

course2.addStudent("Peter Jones");
course2.addStudent("Steve Smith");

System.out.println("Number of students in " +course1.getCourseName() + ":  "
  + course1.getNumberOfStudents());
String[] students = course1.getStudents();
for (int i = 0; i < course1.getNumberOfStudents(); i++)
  System.out.print(students[i] + ", ");

System.out.println();

System.out.print("Number of students in " +course2.getCourseName() +":  "
  + course2.getNumberOfStudents());

System.out.println();

String[] students1 = course2.getStudents();
for (int i = 0; i < course2.getNumberOfStudents(); i++)
  System.out.print(students1[i] + ", ");
  }
}
```

Comment: What's the problem? You haven't asked a specific question, you've just said you want to do X, Y and Z.

Comment: It would probably be easier to use a `List` instead of an array; that avoids all sorts of issues like you're about to step in.

Answer (score 2):

Because this is a homework exercise, and because the aim is for YOU to learn, here are a couple of hints

Take a hard look at this code:

```
  private Student[]
  students = new Student[100];

  public void addStudent(String[] Student) {
    Student[numberOfStudents] = students[];
    numberOfStudents++;
  }
```

Hints:

1. You need to pay more attention to style.

   - The declaration of `students` *looks like* a declaration of some variable called *Student* ... because you split it over two lines in a bizarre place.
   - The declaration of the argument to `addStudent` is wrong.  You should NOT start a variable name with an uppercase letter.  NOT EVER.  In this case, this is *doubly* wrong because you've also got a class called `Student`!

     Now the Java compiler can handle code where there is a class and a variable with the same name.  (The JLS has rules for resolving the mess.)  The problem is that your code may not mean what you think it means ... and that is a bad thing!!
2. This statement is invalid: `Student[numberOfStudents] = students[];`.  The problem is that the RHS has to be an expression, and `students[]` is not an expression.
3. But the fundamental problem with the `addStudent` method is that it does not make sense.  What are you *actually* trying to do here?  Add a `Student` to the `students` array?  If so, why are you passing it an array of strings?  And why are you trying to assign something to that array of Strings?

   I think that you need to change the signature for `addStudent` to `addStudent(Student)`.  Then change the various other things that depend on that method signature ... including the places where you call the method.
4. Finally, it is a bad idea to declare `students` as an array of `Student`.  The problem is that an array has a fixed upper bound.  If you exceed that bound, you get a runtime exception.  In this case, your code will crash if there are more than 100 `Students` in a `Course`.

   There are various ways to deal with this, but the simplest is to use a `List<Student>` instead of a `Student[]`.  This will also help when you implement the `dropStudent` method.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions!  I'll be asking more, and this is the type of answer I like to see :)  My goal is to learn the right way to do things, since my first programming prof didn't teach for crap.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following solution. There were compilation errors that I have fixed.  You should be able to do a diff to know what they were. Hope this helps.

```
public class Student {
private int id;
private String name;
private java.util.Date dateCreated;

public Student(int ssn, String newName) {
    id = ssn;
    name = newName;
    dateCreated = new java.util.Date();
}

public int getID() {
    return id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public java.util.Date getDateCreated() {
    return dateCreated;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return name;
}
}
```

Course.java

```
public class Course {
private String courseName;
private Student[] students = new Student[100];
private int numberOfStudents;

public Course(String courseName) {
    this.courseName = courseName;
}

public void addStudent(String student) {
    this.students[numberOfStudents] = new Student(0,student);
    numberOfStudents++;
}

public Student[] getStudents() {
    return students;
}

public int getNumberOfStudents() {
    return numberOfStudents;
}

public String getCourseName() {
    return courseName;
}

public void dropStudent(String student) {
}
}
```

TestCourse.java

```
public class TestCourse {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Course course1 = new Course("Data Structures");
    Course course2 = new Course("Database Systems");

    course1.addStudent("Peter Jones");
    course1.addStudent("Brian Smith");
    course1.addStudent("Anne Kennedy");

    course2.addStudent("Peter Jones");
    course2.addStudent("Steve Smith");

    System.out.println("Number of students in " + course1.getCourseName() + ":  " + course1.getNumberOfStudents());
    Student[] students = course1.getStudents();
    for (int i = 0; i < course1.getNumberOfStudents(); i++)
        System.out.print(students[i] + ", ");

    System.out.println();

    System.out.print("Number of students in " + course2.getCourseName() + ":  " + course2.getNumberOfStudents());

    System.out.println();

    Student[] students1 = course2.getStudents();
    for (int i = 0; i < course2.getNumberOfStudents(); i++)
        System.out.print(students1[i] + ", ");
}
}
```

Comment: Nice one.  NOT!!  Please don't do peoples homework for them.  It is in **nobody's** best interest.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of issues with the code you have presented, so much so I would suggest you need to refresh some of your basic concepts...

In your `Course` class you define a `addStudent` method...

```
public void addStudent(String[] Student) {
    Student[numberOfStudents] = students[];
    numberOfStudents++;
}
```

This does not even begin to make sense...`Student` is undefined as a variable (it's actually a `class`), which you then seem to be trying to assign `students[]` to it...now `students` is defined as an array of `students` in the `Course` class, but the syntext just doesn't make sense.

You also completely ignoring the `student` variable, which is a `String` type, so I'm not even sure how you were thinking you could assign it to anything....instead, you should be trying to do something like (I think)...

```
public void addStudent(Student student) {
    if (numberOfStudents < 100) {
        students[numberOfStudents] = student;
        numberOfStudents++;
    }
}
```

This checks to see if there are enough empty spaces available and assigns the student to the next available space if it can.  The method "should" throw an `Exception` if the course is full, but least get the basics running first...

This will now course problems for your `main` method, because `addStudent` no long accepts a `String`, but expects a `Student`...

```
// Create a re-usable reference to Peter...
Student peter = new Student(123, "Peter Jones");   
course1.addStudent(peter);
course1.addStudent(new Student(456, "Brian Smith"));
course1.addStudent(new Student(789, "Anne Kennedy"));

course2.addStudent(peter);
course2.addStudent(new Student(135, "Steve Smith"));
```

This should now get things running a little more

Comment: Yeah I figured as much; its been a while since I was coding, my first comp sci professor wasn't that great/didn't teach for crap, and this is meant to help me review  Thanks for the suggestions!

Comment: @DavesNotHere It's a decent attempt, don't get me wrong.  I've being in classes where I've known about the subject than the teacher :P

Answer (score 0):

You say you want to modify the `Student` class to keep track of how many objects are created. A common approach is to add a static field to the class and increment it when the constructor is called:

```
public class Student {
    ...
    public static int globalStudents = 0;
    public Student() { globalStudents++; }
    ...
}
```

All existing constructors must call the default constructor for this to work. Example:

```
public Student(int ssn, String newName) {
    this(); // default constructor
    id = ssn;
    name = newName;
    dateCreated = new java.util.Date();
}
```

If you want to decrement the counter when students are destroyed, you can use `finalize()` (though I see no reason to).

You also say you want `Course` to have an array of students, which you already seem to have. However, it's preferable to use a dynamic container such as [`ArrayList`](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/05/example-of-arraylist-in-java-tutorial.html). The ease and safety of managed lists is so severe, there's almost no reason not to use them.

```
ArrayList<Student> myList = new ArrayList<Student>();
Student s = new Student(123456789, "Jimmy Russell");
myList.add(s);
```

Comment: Cool; thanks for all the suggestions :) That's why I asked here.  Am blowing the dust off of the Java code I already know and I am a bit rusty; been about a year since my last class on this.